Inkscape - focus canvas after selecting elements from "Layers and objects" without losing selection
When I select a couple of elements in the "Layers and objects" menu in Inkscape, and then, say, press [ or ] to rotate, it doesn't work (nothing happens) because the focus is still in the L&O menu. So I need to click on the canvas to focus it, but that loses my selection. The only workaround I've found is to carefully click on the resize layers without actually moving, but this sometimes has side effects like losing part of the selection, accidentally resizing / rotating etc. What is the proper way to go about this?
To clarify further, I can't just select the elements on the canvas because they are in different groups. Ideally I'd like some way to 'group' these elements together but using something else than the regular groups because I already use them for another conceptual grouping. I've found some workarounds like assigning attribute values and then using 'search' but that doesn't work reliable for me, and it still gives me the focus problem (sometimes, can't quite figure out when or why it goes wrong).

I usually just middle-mouse-click the canvas to reset the focus, since that only pans/zooms the view, but you can also press the Esc-key to focus the canvas, as described here (as long as the layers-panel is docked, not a floating window).

Oh right so Esc should have worked? I tried that be maybe there's something else I was doing wrong. Thanks.
